# Pod in status pending but autoscale is enabled, why doesn't work?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, autoscaling

Did you find this behavior before?

I have a GKE cluster with 5 nodes, I have autoscaling enable as you can see below

```
    autoscaling:
  enabled: true
  maxNodeCount: 9
  minNodeCount: 1
config:
  diskSizeGb: 100
  diskType: pd-standard
  imageType: COS
  machineType: n1-standard-1
  oauthScopes:
  - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only
  - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write
  - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring
  - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/servicecontrol
  - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/service.management.readonly
  - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/trace.append
  serviceAccount: default
initialNodeCount: 1
instanceGroupUrls:
- xxx
management:
  autoRepair: true
  autoUpgrade: true
name: default-pool
podIpv4CidrSize: 24
selfLink: xxxx
status: RUNNING
version: 1.13.7-gke.8
```

However when I'm trying to deploy one service I receive this error

```
 Warning  FailedScheduling   106s                default-scheduler   0/5 nodes are available: 3 Insufficient cpu, 4 node(s) didn't match node selector.
  Warning  FailedScheduling   30s (x3 over 106s)  default-scheduler   0/5 nodes are available: 4 node(s) didn't match node selector, 5 Insufficient cpu.
  Normal   NotTriggerScaleUp  0s (x11 over 104s)  cluster-autoscaler  pod didn't trigger scale-up (it wouldn't fit if a new node is added): 1 node(s) didn't match node selector
```

And if I see the stats of my resources I don't see problem with CPU, right?

```
kubectl top node
NAME                                                 CPU(cores)   CPU%   MEMORY(bytes)   MEMORY%   
gke-pre-cluster-1-default-pool-17d2178b-4g9f   106m         11%    1871Mi          70%       
gke-pre-cluster-1-default-pool-17d2178b-g8l1   209m         22%    3042Mi          115%      
gke-pre-cluster-1-default-pool-17d2178b-grvg   167m         17%    2661Mi          100%      
gke-pre-cluster-1-default-pool-17d2178b-l9gt   122m         12%    2564Mi          97%       
gke-pre-cluster-1-default-pool-17d2178b-ppfw   159m         16%    2830Mi          107%
```

So... if the problem seems is not cpu with this message?

And the other thing is... why if there are a problem with resources don't scale up automatically?

Please anyone found this before can explain me? I don't understand.

Thank you so much

Comment: Seems like your Pod's resources are too big to fit one node. Can you post the Pod/Deployment yaml?

Comment: I think this may be quota issue. There are generally 10 core quota in cloud vendors.

Comment: As asked in the first comment, share with us the [resources requests and limits](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-compute-resources-container/#resource-requests-and-limits-of-pod-and-container) so that we can try to start helping you.

Answer (score 0):

GKE's autoscaling functionality is based on Compute Engine [instance groups](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups). As such, it only pays attention to actual, dynamic resource usage (CPU, memory, etc), and not to the `requests` section in a Kubernetes pod template.

A GKE node that has 100% of its resources allocated (and therefore cannot schedule any more pods) is considered idle by the autoscaler if the software running in those pods isn't actually using the resources. If the software running in those pods is waiting for a "Pending" pod to start, then your workload is deadlocked.

Unfortunately, I know of no solution to this problem. If you control the pod templates that are being used to start the pods, you can try asking for less memory/CPU than your jobs actually need. But that might result in pods getting evicted.

GKE's autoscaler isn't particularly smart.

Answer (score -1):

Could you check if you have this entry "*ZONE_RESOURCE_POOL_EXHAUSTED*" in StackDriver logging?

It probably that zone you are using with your kubernetes cluster is with problems.

Regards.